# WebDriver Specific tags

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm using WebDriver and I have a WebElement that has a few root  tags, each of these div tags has multiple div tags within them. Is there a way to get just the root tags?

Eg.
WebElement grabbed from the "someid" field below contains the following data within. I'd like to grab the root div tags from this element (example below has three) By default it grabs the root, and any div tags within, is there a way to just grab those three div tags? There is not specific names or id to grab them, but if I can get the root div tags, I can loop through them easier to locate the data I need in each. Thanks for any direction, or let me know if I need to get more information. Thanks

```
<div id="someid">
    <div><more html that has div tags></div>
    <div><more html that has div tags></div>
    <div><more html that has div tags></div>
</div>

WebElement weMain = driver.findElement(By.id("someid"));
// Looking for a way to just grab the root divs to my WebElement
List<WebElement> weSomeElements = weMain.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
```

Thanks for any direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
List<WebElement> weSomeElements =
    driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("div[id='someid'] div"));
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
WebElement element = weSomeElement.select(n).findElements(by.tagName("div"));
var elementText = element.Text();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting all the divs though.

Comment: yeah that's what this code does it gets all of the divs under the div that has the id=someid.  If there are multiple instances of id=someid then you would get different results.  Once you have the list then you need to select which index you want to get your data.  So if you could edit your question and show the results that may help us to determine the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
driver.findElements(By.xPath("//div[@id='someid']/div")
```

I think that should return the 3 divs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting all the divs though.